# Using word_tokenize to a column of a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I've just started learning text analysis and encountered a problem when trying to tokenize the reviews column in the IMDB movie reviews dataset.

My own line of code:

```
reviews_tokenized = word_tokenize(df\['review'\].astype(str))
```

And I got an error message by running it:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I'm confused because I thought I've converted the data type by astype(str)

If using apply() then everything went well:

```
reviews_tokenized = df\["review"\].astype(str).apply(word_tokenize)
```

And th example code is:

```
reviews_tokenized = df.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row\['review'\]), axis=1)
```

I'm curious about what went wrong in my original version, and what's the difference between these three
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`word_tokenize` expect a text (a string) that will be split into words. It doesn't expect a list (a Series). So when you use `apply` or `map`, Pandas iterates over all rows and call the function `word_tokenize` with each row (the text).

You can consider `apply` or `map` acts as a loop. Equivalent code:

```
reviews_tokenized = [word_tokenize(row) for row in df['review'].astype(str)]
```